# Unable to add a file in repository with minus red sign. Visual Studio 17/TFS/Git

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual studio 17.

I have created a new file which is out of solution but is still in the repository of git.

I am unable to see this new file in my changes hence I can't check it in.

When I navigate through directory view, it show me the file that I have added but it has a red minus sign with it. Right clicking this file doesn't give me any option to add it to the repository. I want this file in my pending changes.

[image]

What can I do to make it part of my pending changes?

Comment: Is the file being ignored? Do you see the file when you do a `git status`? You can show ignored files with `git status --ignoredl`

Comment: @ Not using git through command line, I see pending changes in Team Explorer.

Comment: Can you look at your `.gitignore`?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I haven't tested it yet, but I think looking into .gitignore will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to make it part of my pending changes?

Just like Philippe and EncryptedWatermelon said, the red minus icon in source control is generally used to indicate that the file is ignored.

To make it part of your pending changes, there is an option **Add Ignored File to Source Control...** when you right lick on this file:

[image]

After add this file to source control, we could see it in the pending changes, or you can check your `.gitignore` file, and move this file from that file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The minus icons is for ignored files.

Look at your `.gitignore` file and adapt or remove the line that ignore this file.